# Write 0 as masked textbox mask

Tags: regex, kendo-ui, kendo-maskedtextbox

I am using Kendo masked text box widget to mask the input. The input should be of form 
HR-D001-XXXX where "001" should actually be "001" and user shouldn't be able to write or edit that part of the field. The "XXXX" should be any four digits (that one is easy).

So, my question, is there a way to teach Kendo to treat 0 as a 0 inside a regex rule for maskedTextBox, and some other value (for exampl d) as it used to treat 0? That way I could write expression like HR-D001-dddd?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about defining the `mask` as `HR-D\0\01-0000``

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#example").kendoMaskedTextBox({
    mask: "HR-D\\0\\01-0000"
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.1008/styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.1008/styles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.1008/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.1008/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>

<input id="example"/>
```

Comment: Thanks man. I wrote "\0" instead of double "\", forgot that \0 means something totally different #dummy